# I have a num mentioned in C1 cell (20), I have to insert 20 rows below C1 , if I have 30 in C1 cell then I need to insert 30 rows Below C1 VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a number mentioned in C1 cell (20), I have to insert 20 rows below C1. If I have 30 in C1 cell then I need to insert 30 rows Below C1.

Please help with VBA macro

Answer (score 1):

This can be done quite easily:

```
For i = 1 To Range("C1"):
Rows("4:4").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next i
```

Just take care that you know starting at which row you want to do this.