# Insert numbered cells + row based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, insert, row, cell

I have managed to insert rows based on cell value for instance if A1 cell is 20, I run the macro, 20 rows appear under A1, those rows are blank right, I need the 20 new cells below A1 to be number 1 to 20 ( the number in A1) let me know if possible.

Cheers Adrien

Comment: Can you provide the macro code? Have you aleady tried to put your macro ocde into a for loop?

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/72712595/4961700

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/q/24489376/4961700

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub counter()
Dim i as integer
for i = 2 to cells(1, 1) + 1
    cells(i, 1) = i - 1
next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Insert an Integer Sequence Below a Cell

**A Basic Example For the Active Sheet**

- Note that this doesn't insert rows, it just writes the integer sequence to the cells below `A1`.

```vb
Sub IntegersBelow()
    With Range("A1")
        .Resize(.Value).Offset(1).Value _
            = .Worksheet.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & CStr(.Value) & ")")
    End With
End Sub
```

**Applied to Your Actual Use Case**

[image]

- Adjust the values in the constants section.

```vb
Sub InsertIntegersBelow()
 
    ' Use constants to change their values in one place instead
    ' of searching for them in the code (each may be used multiple times).
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const fRow As Long = 3
    Const Col As String = "E"
    
    ' Reference the workbook ('wb').
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing the code
    
    ' Reference the worksheet ('ws').
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    ' Calculate the last row ('lRow'),
    ' the row of the last non-empty cell in the column.
    Dim lRow As Long: lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Validate the last row.
    If lRow < fRow Then
        MsgBox "No data in column range.", vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim cCell As Range ' Current Cell
    Dim cValue As Variant ' Current Cell Value
    Dim r As Long ' Current Row
    
    For r = lRow To fRow Step -1 ' loop backwards
        Set cCell = ws.Cells(r, Col) ' reference the current cell...
        cValue = cCell.Value ' ... and write its value to a variable
        If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
            cValue = CLng(cValue) ' ensure whole number
            If cValue > 0 Then ' greater than 0
                ' Insert the rows.
                cCell.Offset(1).Resize(cValue) _
                    .EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
                With cCell.Offset(1).Resize(cValue)
                    ' Write the values.
                    .Value = ws.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & cValue & ")")
                    ' Apply formatting.
                    .ClearFormats
                    .Font.Bold = True
                End With
            'Else ' less than or equal to zero; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' is not a number
        End If
    Next r
    
    MsgBox "Rows inserted.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the space where you comment on my answer. If you need to keep the format of the numbered cells, in the code out-comment (or delete) the two lines below `'Apply formatting`.

Comment: Hi mate, thanks again, all good now.